# jquery Отрицание

Tags: jquery

Конструкция, которая скрывает все элементы, у которых `checkbox:checked`.

```
$('.list input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
})
```

Как применить отрицание к условию, чтобы скрывались элементы, которые не checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать селектор [`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$('.list input:checkbox:not(:checked)').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
})
```

Или аналогичный метод [`.not`](https://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$('.list input:checkbox').not(':checked').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
})
```

Кроме того, можно отказаться от `.each`, так как большинство методов `jQuery` заточены на работу с коллекциями. Код может выглядеть так:

```
$('.list input:checkbox').not(':checked').parent().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="value1">
<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="value2">
<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="value3" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="value4">
<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="value5" checked>
```